# Identify manufacturers of trimmer potentiometer and capacitor in photos

Tags: capacitor, identification, potentiometer

Can somebody identify these manufacturers (marked in red rectangle)?

[image: Photo showing trimmer potentiometer and capacitor]

Comment: Did you do a google search?

Comment: Yes, at least of the yellow component (https://www.electronicspoint.com/forums/resources/logos-for-electronic-component-manufacturers.47/)

Comment: Is that a google image search?

Comment: No, picture(s) are taken by me.

Comment: why do you need to know? Left is a pretty standard looking potentiometer / trimmer, right looks like a run-of-the-mill film capacitor. What do you hope to achieve by knowing the manufacturers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trimpot looks like a clone of a Piher made by Iskra (former Yugoslavia, now Slovenia I believe).

[image]

The capacitor might be Thompson CSF logo.

[image]

Both are pretty jellybean-ish parts.